# default classpath current directory anomaly

Tags: java, classpath

I am trying to compile and run simple Java program. This program basically prints out hello world phrase. I am not specifying -cp option and I don't have CLASSPATH environment variable. Hence the user classpath is limited only to current directory.

Now, compilation works beautifully.

```
rustam@rustam-laptop:~/temp/bird_test$ javac Sparrow.java
```

This command produces needed .class file. The weird stuff happens when I try to run .class file. The following command works good.

```
rustam@rustam-laptop:~/temp/bird_test$ java Sparrow
```

But when I try the following command

```
rustam@rustam-laptop:~/temp/bird_test$ java ./Sparrow
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ..Sparrow
```

WTF! i thought that symbol ./ refers to current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java` takes a class name as argument. It doesn't take a file path. The class name (Sparrow) is then resolved by the java class loader to a .class file based on the classpath, i.e. it looks for a `Sparrow.class` file in every directory and jar listed in the classpath.

Let's take an example that respects good practices, and thus doesn't use the default package:

```
package foo.bar;

public class Baz {
    ...
}
```

The class name of the above class is `foo.bar.Baz`. To execute it, you must use

```
java foo.bar.Baz
```

and java will look for a `foo/bar/Baz.class` in all the directories listed in the classpath. So if the classpath is set to `/hello/world`, it will look for the file `/hello/world/foo/bar/Baz.class`.